# on click anchor has a child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

hi 
shortly I want to make the card as one block to return the href of anchor when click on any where in the card.
the problem now, when I click on any place of the card its return the item that I clicked.
and the code is show the problem.

am sorry for my bad language.
thanks for help

```js
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var ele = $(e.target);
  if (ele.hasClass('itemLink')) {
    // I want this part
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(ele.attr('href'));
  } else {
    console.log(ele.attr('class'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer" style="width: 200px;">
  <a class="itemLink" href="#">
    <div class="itemCard">
      <div class="itemHead">
        <img class="itemImage" src="image.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
        <h3 class="itemName">Item Name</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="itemDetails">
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something when you click anywhere inside the `a` tag, including on one of it's children. This should work:

```js
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
  var ele = $(e.target).closest('a.itemLink');
  if (ele.length) {
    // the click was inside your anchor
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(ele.attr('href'));
  } else {
    // the click was not in your anchor
    console.log('clicked not in anchor');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer" style="width: 200px;">
  <a class="itemLink" href="#">
    <div class="itemCard">
      <div class="itemHead">
        <img class="itemImage" src="image.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
        <h3 class="itemName">Item Name</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="itemDetails">
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for answer,
great this solve the problem, that's what am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Bind your event handler to the anchor, not the document.

```js
$('a.itemLink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemContainer" style="width: 200px;">
  <a class="itemLink" href="#">
    <div class="itemCard">
      <div class="itemHead">
        <img class="itemImage" src="image.png" style="width:200px; height:200px;">
        <h3 class="itemName">Item Name</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="itemDetails">
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">item detail descriptins</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

If the anchors are added dynamically, use delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.itemLink', ...)
```

Comment: thanks for answer<br>
but I need to keep bind do the document to keep listening if I change the content

Comment: That's what delegation does. You should delegate from the closest element that you don't replace dynamically. I assumed `.itemContainer` is static and `.itemLink` is dynamic, but you can use `document` if that's the only static element.

Comment: Don't use `.bind()` unless you have to use jQuery older than 1.7. You should use `.on()` for delegation.